# Packaging custom aws-java-sdk-bundle jar with maven

Tags: amazon-web-services, maven, aws-java-sdk

I am trying to customize the `aws-java-sdk-bundle` and packaging it with those modifications I made on my repo (specifically I modified the `AmazonS3Client`) . So far I have tried modifying the dependency in `pom.xml` to use the local `aws-sdk` jar instead of pulling it from maven:

```
--- a/aws-java-sdk-bundle/pom.xml
+++ b/aws-java-sdk-bundle/pom.xml
@@ -24,6 +24,8 @@
         <artifactId>aws-java-sdk</artifactId>
         <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
         <optional>false</optional>
+        <scope>system</scope>
+        <systemPath>${project.basedir}/../aws-java-sdk/target/aws-java-sdk-1.11.271.jar</systemPath>
         <version>1.11.271</version>
     </dependency>
 </dependencies>
```

However, the result is that the bundle `jar` is empty. This is because as I realized, the `aws-sdk` is also empty if I try to package it:

```
$ mvn package -Dmaven.test.skip 
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] 
[INFO] ---------------------< com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk >---------------------
[INFO] Building AWS SDK For Java 1.11.271
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ aws-java-sdk ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /home/user/ftx/aws-sdk-java/aws-java-sdk/src/main/resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.6.0:compile (default-compile) @ aws-java-sdk ---
[INFO] No sources to compile
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @ aws-java-sdk ---
[INFO] Not copying test resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.6.0:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ aws-java-sdk ---
[INFO] Not compiling test sources
[INFO] No sources to compile
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.19.1:test (default-test) @ aws-java-sdk ---
[INFO] Tests are skipped.
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-jar-plugin:2.4:jar (default-jar) @ aws-java-sdk ---
[WARNING] JAR will be empty - no content was marked for inclusion!
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  2.339 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2021-12-06T01:36:25-08:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

My question is: what is a recommended way on how to build the `aws-sdk-bundle` jar from local sources. (I want the bundle to contain my custom classes.)

Comment: First question: Why do you customize: `aws-java-sdk-bundle` ? Why not using it as it... ?

Comment: I need a functionality that the SDK doesn't provide.